# Flutter: How to show Android Fragment inside Flutter widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I have Android fragment which runs camera using third party library for scanning documents identity purposes. Is it possible to show that fragment inside flutter widget ? Using Flutter PlatformViews we can only show Views

Comment: You can look at platform channels instead to call a method that will call your camera activity with it's fragment

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: @Develocode777 Being more precise I need to create wrapper in flutter for ready native sdk which use internally fragment with for camera scanning.

Comment: @FPerroch yes I know about channels but I need to implement something like step1= flutter widget step2=camera step3=flutter widget and so on, something like guide for user so after each step I need to run Activity to show camera scanner, I would like to run Activity once and show/hide camera and flutter widget

Comment: You can't show/hide an Android activity from your flutter Widget. But you can call your Android activity with plateform channels and return the scanned data to your Flutter widget and start over as many times as you want. Be care of memory consumption by closing your Camera's